# how to check if value is not empty inside a list and exclude empty list cases?

Tags: mongodb

I have this model:

```
{
  "personId": 1,
  "name": "jack",
  "aliasses": [
    {
      "aliasName": "rob"
    },
    {
      "aliasName": "mark"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to query all the docs where `name` = empty string ("") and `aliasName` first child `!= ""`,  so I wrote this:

```
db.people.find({name: "", "aliasses.aliasName": {$ne: ""}}).count()
```

the problem is, if I have a collection with only two docs and one of them have empty list in `aliasses`, like this:

```
{
    "personId" : 3,
    "name" : "",
    "aliasses" : [
        {
            "aliasName" : "rob"
        },
        {
            "aliasName" : "mark"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "personId" : 4,
    "name" : "",
    "aliasses" : [ ]
}
```

and then I run my query above, I will get 2, instead of 1...

I only want to find the case where `name` is empty string "" and `aliasName` is `!=  ""` (only if aliasses is bigger than 1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$ne` if you want to check for the non empty array

```
db.people.find({ "name": "", "aliasses": { "$ne": [] }}).count()
```

And if you want to check for the first element inside the aliasses

```
db.collection.find({
  "name": "",
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      { "$ne": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$aliasses.aliasName", 0] }, ""] },
      { "$ne": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$aliasses.aliasName", 0] }, undefined] },
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution:

```
db.people.find({name: "", $where: "this.aliasses.length >= 1" ,"aliasses.aliasName": {$ne: ""}})
```